# Django Import error: cannot import "name"

Tags: python, django

SOLVED

I got an error i dont understand: cannot import name "UserUpdateForm" from "users.forms".

Im doing the django tutorial from corey schafer, and we are creating a form as a class to update the users profiles of a blog page, then importing it to views.py and calling it in a function and when i try to run the server it pops up that error. I already looked for other questions but in general they say that the problem is a circular import, but i cant figure if it is my case and where it is. Im relatively new to programming so i dont really understand how this works, any help will be aprecciated:

(Already tried to import the UserUpdateForm inside my profile function and didnt work)

**Forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from .models import Profile

class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ["username", "email", "password1", "password2"]

class UserUptadeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ["username", "email"]

class ProfileUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ["image"]
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib import messages
from .forms import UserRegisterForm, UserUpdateForm, ProfileUpdateForm
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required



def register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get("username")
            messages.success(request, f"Your account has been created! You are now able to log")
            return redirect("login")
    else:
        form = UserRegisterForm()
    return render(request,"users/register.html",{"form": form})

@login_required
def profile(request):
    u_form = UserUpdateForm.forms()
    p_form = ProfileUpdateForm.forms()

    context= {
    "u_form": u_form,
    "p_form": p_form
    }
    return render(request, "users/profile.html")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename the form in `forms.py` from `UserUptadeForm` to `UserUpdateForm` (switch the letters `d` and `t`)